# How to cast someobject.getClass() to Class<Object> without SuppressWarnings("unchecked")?

Tags: java, casting

I'm trying to serialize several different objects with one single method using JAXB:

Boiled down code:

```
public static void serialize(Object req) {
    QName qname = ...
    Class<Object> type = helper(req);
    Object obj = req;

    ...

    JAXBElement elem = new JAXBElement<Object>(qname, type, obj);

    ...
}
```

Now JAXB expects variable `type` to be of type `Class<Object>` (at least I think so), so I introduced this helper method:

```
private static Class<Object> helper(Object req) {
    return (Class<Object>) req.getClass(); // UNCHECKED CAST!
}
```

But this last line of code produces an unchecked cast warning.
How can I get it right?

Comment: Use `Class<?>` instead. Also, it's a warning, just use the `@SupressWarnings("unchecked")` and move on.

Comment: that is, `@SuppressWarnings` with two `p`'s.

Comment: Class<?> doesn't work, JAXBElement complains about it.
Also I think Java designers don't generate this warning without reason, so I want to get it to compile without warning, avoiding "SuppressWarnings".

Comment: @pjp Its normal to have tons of @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") in some classes, take a look at the source of the collections framework for example: ArrayList alone already contains 14.

Comment: @pjp why do you want to avoid `@SupressWarnings`? There's nothing wrong with it. If it's a matter of *style*, then you're overthinking too much about it.

Comment: I've read somewhere about "Heap pollution": http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Topic2

Comment: in this scenario, you can't avoid the suppression.  it's a fact of life often associated with "serialization" type scenarios.  it's really a "weakness" around how the `JAXBElement` class was defined.

Comment: Yours **is not** a case of heap pollution. Also, there's nothing wrong in what you're currently doing and adding `@SupressWarnings`. I would really focus on this problem if it raises an exception at runtime and it is demonstrated by stacktrace or usage of a profiler.

Comment: By the way, looks like you're trying to consume a web service from JAX-WS. It would be way better to use a tool like wsimport to generate the necessary classes to consume the XML instead of writing it manually.

Comment: Actually, this is part of a SOAP message queue. Messages are only removed from the queue when transmission was successful. I've used wsimport to generate the classes ("messages").

Comment: Note that wsimport also provide classes to consume the Web Service and these auto generated classes have `@SupressWarnings` in them. Is that *heap pollution* as well?

Comment: I dont't know. That's why im asking for expert opinion on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Here you have a well detailed answer about: [Java Heap Pollution](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/155994/102805). After reading the answer, I can say that yours is not a case of heap pollution at all.

Comment: Ok, so I go with SuppressWarnings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following

```
req.getClass().asSubclass(Object.class);
```

Comment: Produces the same warning:
    `required: Class<Object>
    found:    Class<CAP#1>
    where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
        CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ? extends Object`

Comment: @pjp that's not a warning, that looks like a compiler error, and that's what you should avoid.

Comment: It's a warning. I just removed the unnessecary stuff.